# How to publish correctly my Gradle plugin into mavenLocal

Tags: java, gradle

I'm develop a simple plugin for gradle. I've bootstraped the project for the plugin throught:

```
gradle init
```

And I choose Java and Groovy (DSL).

First of all, I've added the `maven-publish` plugin to have all the necessary for deploying. Also, in the `build.gradle` I added the version (1.0.0-SNAPSHOT).

I run build and publishToMavenLocal and I haven't errors.

With the same procedure `gradle init` I've created a sample application. I've imported the plugin throught their id, obviosuly after update the repositories with mavenLocal (everything, buildscript also).

Until this, I have always the same error:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.myplugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

What I missing?!?

Thanks!